# Spinner contains week days, how can I select the default day depending on the device day

Tags: java, android, calendar, android-spinner, dayofweek

I'm trying here to create a java class to:

1. check the device day.
2. Create a spinner that contains all week days.
3. Spinner will select the default day depending on the device/computer day.
4. User can select another day from the spinner.
5. User click the "next" button to go to another form.
6. Spinner will send intent by the chosen day to that form.

it's not doing the process well, it is selecting Thursday even when I  change the device day to Sunday, it keep selecting Thursday as default selection.

code :

```
public class InformationCustomerListSelectDay extends LiteActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView txtSelectDayTitle, txtSelectDateTitle;
    Spinner spinnerSelectDay;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    Button btnNext;
    private String[] arraySpinner;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.layout_information_customer_list_select_day);

        String from = getIntent().getStringExtra("FROM");
        if(from.equals("ByDayOfWeek")) {

            this.arraySpinner = new String[]{
                    "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"};

            toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.layout_information_customer_list_details_select_day_toolbar);
            txtSelectDayTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.layout_information_customer_list_details_select_day_title);
            txtSelectDateTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.layout_information_customer_list_details_select_date_title);
            spinnerSelectDay = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.layout_information_customer_list_details_select_day_spinner);
            btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.layout_information_customer_list_details_select_day_btn);

            btnNext.setOnClickListener(this);

            SimpleDateFormat dayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            Date d = new Date();
            Calendar calendar = null;
            try {
                calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.setTime(d);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String dayOfTheWeek = dayFormat.format(d);
            String dateOfTheWeek = dateFormat.format(d);
            txtSelectDayTitle.setText(dayOfTheWeek);
            txtSelectDateTitle.setText(dateOfTheWeek);

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, arraySpinner);
            spinnerSelectDay.setAdapter(adapter);
            int day = calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK;

            if(calendar != null ){
                if (day == 1) {
                    spinnerSelectDay.setSelection(6);
                }
                else if (day == 7) {
                    spinnerSelectDay.setSelection(5);
                }
                else if (day == 6) {
                    spinnerSelectDay.setSelection(4);
                }
                else if (day == 5) {
                    spinnerSelectDay.setSelection(3);
                }
                else if (day == 4) {
                    spinnerSelectDay.setSelection(2);
                }
                else if (day == 3) {
                    spinnerSelectDay.setSelection(1);
                }
                else if (day == 2) {
                    spinnerSelectDay.setSelection(0);
                }


            }

            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Day Select");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.layout_information_customer_list_details_select_day_btn:
                Intent intentAllRoutCustomer = new Intent(InformationCustomerListSelectDay.this,InformationCustomerListDetails.class);
                String spinnerIntent = spinnerSelectDay.getSelectedItem().toString();
                intentAllRoutCustomer.putExtra("FROM", "ByDayOfWeek");
                intentAllRoutCustomer.putExtra("VALUE", spinnerIntent);
                startActivity(intentAllRoutCustomer);
                break;

            default:

    }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are probably using calendar incorrectly. instead of this:

```
int day = calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK;
```

you probably need to do this:

```
int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have all day list in ascending order

```
 public int getCurrentDayInt()
        {
            calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            dateFormat = new DateFormatSymbols(Locale.getDefault());

            return  calendar.get(calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        }
```

then use `sppiner.setSelected(getCurrentDayInt);`

Use this method to get current Day in form of String

```
 public String getCurrentDay()
    {
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        dateFormat = new DateFormatSymbols(Locale.getDefault());
        intDAY = calendar.get(calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        return  dateFormat.getWeekdays()[intDAY];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please give this working code a try.

```
public class InformationCustomerListSelectDay extends AppCompatActivity {

        // Array that defines days of the week.
        String[] weekdays = new String[]{"Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"};

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout. layout_information_customer_list_select_day);

            //Get the day of the week for perticular device
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
            Date d = new Date();
            String dayOfTheWeek = sdf.format(d);

            // Get the array index from day of the week.
            int defaultPosition = Arrays.asList(weekdays).indexOf(dayOfTheWeek);

            // Apply index to spinner.
            spinnerSelectDay.setSelection(defaultPosition);
        }

    }
```